# Use dedicated per-user log file for cron and?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, cron

On Ubuntu 12.04 how can I configure `cron` to log to a particular file when it runs jobs as a particular user? I am interested in redirecting both the messages that go into `auth.log` and those going into `syslog`.

Comment: In this case you actually need to configure your logging daemon, not cron. Cron just sends it's messages to syslog, and then your log daemon determines what file to go into. You can configure your log daemon to extract the user from the message and change the destination based on the user.

Comment: @Patrick could you elaborate your last sentence please?

Comment: @lalebarde yeah, at the time of the comment I also didn't find it very helpful. By now I know, that several logging daemons, such as rsyslogd allow you to configure where messages end up, based on where they come from or what user logged them.

Comment: Great, but auditd has no option for this and it is the provider of admins logs instead of syslog family

Comment: @0xC0000022L [auditd can be chained with rsyslog](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-send-audit-logs-to-remote-rsyslog-server-in-centos-rhel-67/), then your solution should work

Comment: Ah, nice. Thanks for taking the time to add this into a comment. May help future internauts in search of the same thing.